# GWT view reloads when I display another view

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I have an application with a number of views. The sequence I am following is that when the application starts it displays the "Login" view. When I login the "SelectPerson" view is displayed showing the selectable images of a number of people. When I select an image the "AwardOverview" view is displayed. I then select the Button to go back to the "SelectPerson" view which is displayed. However, the "Loading Award Overview, please wait ..." (a pop up in the "AwardOverview" view) message also appears. This indicates that the "AwardOverview" view is also reloading in the background despite the line "rootPanel.remove(AwardOverview);". The code is below.

How do I properly remove the "AwardOverview" view (once I have this information I will implement it for all views).

Regards,

Glyn

```
package org.AwardTracker.client;
/**
 * The purpose of this package is to define the 
 * entry point classes onModuleLoad(). List each
 * view below.
 * If you add a view here then also update NavHandler.java.
 */


import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

/**
 * Entry point classes define <code>onModuleLoad()</code>.
 */
public class AwardTracker implements EntryPoint {

public void onModuleLoad() {

    NavHandler nav = new NavHandler(RootPanel.get());
    nav.setLogin(new LoginView(nav));
    nav.setNewAccount(new CreateAccountView(nav));
    nav.setUpdateAccount(new UpdateAccountView(nav));
    nav.setSelectPerson(new SelectPersonView(nav));
    nav.setAwardOverview(new AwardOverviewView(nav));
    nav.setAwardGroup(new AwardGroupView(nav));
    nav.setEditYouthMember(new EditYouthMemberView(nav));
    nav.setEditAwards1(new EditAwardsView1(nav));
    nav.setEditAwards2(new EditAwardsView2(nav));
    nav.setEditAwards3(new EditAwardsView3(nav));
    nav.setAccountUpdate(new AccountUpdateView(nav));
    nav.setYouthMemberList(new YouthMemberListView(nav));
    nav.setScoutAward(new ScoutAwardView(nav));
    nav.setAwardStock(new AwardStockView(nav));

    RootPanel.get().add(new LoginView(nav));
    }

}

package org.AwardTracker.client;
/**
 * The purpose of this package is to define the 
 * widgets that make up the Award Tracker views.
 * If you add a view here also update AwardTracker.java.
 */

import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;

public class NavHandler {

private RootPanel rootPanel;
private Widget login;
private Widget createAccount;
private Widget updateAccount;
private Widget selectPerson;
private Widget awardOverview;
private Widget awardGroup;
private Widget editYouthMember;
private Widget editAwards1;
private Widget editAwards2;
private Widget editAwards3;
private Widget accountUpdate;
private Widget youthMemberList;
private Widget scoutAward;
private Widget awardStock;

public NavHandler(RootPanel rootPanel2) {
    this.rootPanel = rootPanel2;
}

public void go(String code) {
    rootPanel.clear();
    RootPanel.get().clear();
    login.removeFromParent();
    createAccount.removeFromParent();
    updateAccount.removeFromParent();
    selectPerson.removeFromParent();
    awardOverview.removeFromParent();
    awardGroup.removeFromParent();
    editYouthMember.removeFromParent();
    editAwards1.removeFromParent();
    editAwards2.removeFromParent();
    editAwards3.removeFromParent();
    accountUpdate.removeFromParent();
    youthMemberList.removeFromParent();
    scoutAward.removeFromParent();
    awardStock.removeFromParent();


    if (code.equalsIgnoreCase("Login")){
        rootPanel.add(login);
    }else if (code.equalsIgnoreCase("CreateAccount")){
        rootPanel.add(createAccount);
    }else if (code.equalsIgnoreCase("UpdateAccount")){
        rootPanel.add(updateAccount);
    }else if (code.equalsIgnoreCase("SelectPerson")){
        rootPanel.add(selectPerson);
    }else if (code.equalsIgnoreCase("AwardOverview")){
        rootPanel.add(awardOverview);
    }else if (code.equalsIgnoreCase("AwardGroup")){
        rootPanel.add(awardGroup);
    }else if (code.equalsIgnoreCase("EditYouthMember")){
        rootPanel.add(editYouthMember);
    }else if (code.equalsIgnoreCase("EditAwards1")){
        rootPanel.add(editAwards1);
    }else if (code.equalsIgnoreCase("EditAwards2")){
        rootPanel.add(editAwards2);
    }else if (code.equalsIgnoreCase("EditAwards3")){
        rootPanel.add(editAwards3);
    }else if (code.equalsIgnoreCase("AccountUpdate")){
        rootPanel.add(accountUpdate);
    }else if (code.equalsIgnoreCase("YouthMemberList")){
        rootPanel.add(youthMemberList);
    }else if (code.equalsIgnoreCase("ScoutAward")){
        rootPanel.add(scoutAward);
    }else if (code.equalsIgnoreCase("AwardStock")){
        rootPanel.add(awardStock);
        }

}

public void setLogin(Widget view) {
    login = view;
}

public void setNewAccount(Widget view) {
    createAccount = view;
}

public void setUpdateAccount(Widget view) {
    updateAccount = view;
}

public void setSelectPerson(Widget view) {
    selectPerson = view;    
}

public void setAwardOverview(Widget view) {
    awardOverview = view;
}

public void setAwardGroup(Widget view) {
    awardGroup = view;
}


public void setEditYouthMember(Widget view) {
    editYouthMember = view;
}

public void setEditAwards1(Widget view) {
    editAwards1 = view;
}

public void setEditAwards2(Widget view) {
    editAwards2 = view;
}

public void setEditAwards3(Widget view) {
    editAwards3 = view;
}

public void setAccountUpdate(Widget view) {
    accountUpdate = view;
}

public void setYouthMemberList(Widget view) {
    youthMemberList = view;
}

public void setScoutAward(Widget view) {
    scoutAward = view;
}

public void setAwardStock(Widget view) {
    awardStock = view;
}

}
```

Button to return to "SelectPerson" view:

```
//Add each button to the horizontal panel.
btnSelectYM.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    navHandler2.go("SelectPerson");
    }
});
btnSelectYM.setStyleName("gwt-PushButton-up");
btnSelectYM.setText("Select Youth Member");
btnSelectYM.setWidth("184px");
btnSelectYM.setHeight("40px");
horizontalPanel.add(btnSelectYM);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [Widget#removeFromParent()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.html#removeFromParent%28%29) that removes this widget from its parent widget, if one exists.

Use

```
AwardOverview.removeFromParent();
```

instead of

```
rootPanel.remove(AwardOverview);
```

OR

try with [Panel#clear()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Panel.html#clear%28%29) that removes all child widgets.

```
RootPanel.get().clear();'
```

OR

try with [RootPanel#clear(boolean)](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RootPanel.html#clear%28boolean%29) that clears the rootPanel. If clearDom is true, then also remove any DOM elements that are not widgets.

Note: Respect [Java Naming Convention](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html).

Comment: Hi Braj, I tried each of these in turn and none were successful. The "RootPanel.clear(boolean)" did not work with "Multiple markers at this line
 - Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method clear() from the 
  type Panel
 - Syntax error on token "boolean", delete this token". I then tried all of them just to make sure. Thank you for your help, Glyn.

Comment: I have a temporary fix. However, I really would like to fix it properly. Using and needing to clear multiple views can not be uncommon. Regards, Glyn.  //TODO This if statement has been added as a temporary fix
    //to this being triggered a second time when going to another view.
    if (initialLoad == 0) {
     initialLoad = 1;
     AsyncCallback<ViewData> callback = new ViewDataHandler<ViewData>(AwardOverviewView.this);
     rpc.getViewData(callback);
    }else{
     initialLoad = 0;
    }

Comment: Or should I be setting .clear() for every widget when I exit (there could be 50+ widgets in some cases)? Or is this something I should do in addition to removing the view?. I did a search for DOM and could not find any. Regards, Glyn.

Comment: I tried setting .clear() for every widget when I exit and removing my temporary code and the view I exited is still active in the background. So I really do need to find a way to remove/clear/kill the view when I exit/start a new view. This is slowing my application down as it is loading a lot of information in the background. Regards, Glyn.

Comment: Oh, and I have corrected my disrespect in NavHandler.java. Thanks for spotting that. Regards, Glyn.